# Show that $Y$ is complete.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$, $Y$ be normed linear spaces and $T \in B(X,Y)$. Show that if $X$ is complete and $T$ is an onto open map, then $Y$ is complete.

where, $B(X,Y)$ are bounded linear functions from $ X$ to $Y$.

Can anyone give me some hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ be open and surjective, then there is a constant $C$ such that $ \forall y \in Y$ there is an $x \in T^{-1}(y)$ such that $$\|x\|_X \le C\|y\|_Y.$$

**Proof:** $T(B_X(0,1))$ is open, then it contains an open ball centered at $0 \in Y$: $B_Y(0,\epsilon) \subset T(B_X(0,1))$. Let $y \in T(X) \setminus \{0\}$. Then $$z := \frac{\epsilon}{2}\frac{y}{\|y\|_Y} \in B_Y(0,\epsilon) \subset T_X(B(0,1)),$$ and thus there exists $x_0 \in B_X(0,1)$ with $T(x_0) = z.$ Note that by linearity of $T$, $$T(x_0) = z = \frac{\epsilon}{2}\frac{y}{\|y\|_Y} \Longrightarrow T\Big(\frac{2\|y\|_Y}{\epsilon}x_0\Big) = y.$$ Set $x = \frac{2\|y\|_Y}{\epsilon}x_0.$ Then $T(x) = y$ and, since $x_0 \in B_X(0,1)$, we have $$\|x\|_X = \frac{2\|y\|_Y}{\epsilon}\|x_0\|_X \le \frac{2\|y\|_Y}{\epsilon}.$$ Hence the claim holds with $C = \frac{2}{\epsilon}.$ $\blacksquare$

---

Now take a Cauchy sequence in $Y$ and pull it back to the *complete* space $X$ via $T^{-1}$, making sure to pick $x \in T^{-1}(y)$ as in the above proposition.

Comment: Can you explain why $T$ is open $\implies$ there exist a constant $C$ with the above property?

Comment: @anubhav: I have included a proof of the statement, which I have slightly modified (I have also required that the map is surjective, this way I don't have to worry to intersect with $T(X)$ every time). Let me know what you think! :)

Comment: Thanks, the main part of the proof was to prove that there exist such $C$.

Comment: Yeah, once you have that it all follows easily, that's why I didn't include the proof when you only asked for a hint. Anyways, I am glad you liked my solution :)

Comment: $\|x_n\| \leq C\|y_n\|$ and $\|x_m\| \leq C\|y_m\|$ with $Tx_n=y_n$ and $Tx_m=y_m$ does not yield $\|x_n-x_m\|\leq C \|y_n-y_m\|$.